# Spacing problem between Header and Sidebar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm programming a page and I have a Header and a Sidebar but I'm in trouble with the top property overlapping my header, the sidebar would have to have the top value zeroed but in this scenario it overlaps my header by changing the value to 10 for example I solve this problem of overlapping but create an unwanted spacing when Scrolling. I am new to the world of web design but I have tried several solutions for such an event but none solves such a occurred.

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}


/* Header */

header .navbar {
  font-size: 15px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(260deg, #c16ecf 0%, #2376ae 100%);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

header #navbarNavAltMarkup {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

header #navbarNavAltMarkup .nav-link {
  color: #fff;
  transition: all ease 0.2s;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

header #navbarNavAltMarkup .nav-link:hover {
  color: #081145;
  transition: all ease 0.2s;
}

header #navbarNavAltMarkup .active {
  color: #081145;
  font-weight: 400;
}

header #navbarNavAltMarkup .dropbtn {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

header #navbarNavAltMarkup .dropbtn:hover,
.dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
}

header #navbarNavAltMarkup .dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

header #navbarNavAltMarkup .dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: transparent;
  min-width: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

header #navbarNavAltMarkup .dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

header #navbarNavAltMarkup .dropdown a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

header #navbarNavAltMarkup .show {
  display: block;
}


/* Test */


/* Mobile */

header .navbar-nav {
  align-items: center;
}


/* End Header */


/* Aside */

.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 10;
  height: 100%;
  width: 78px;
  /* background-image: linear-gradient(260deg, #2376ae 0%,#c16ecf 100%); */
  background: #11101D;
  padding: 2px 14px;
  z-index: 99;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.sidebar.open {
  width: 250px;
}

.sidebar .logo-details {
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.sidebar .logo-details .icon {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.sidebar .logo-details .logo_name {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.sidebar.open .logo-details .icon,
.sidebar.open .logo-details .logo_name {
  opacity: 1;
}

.sidebar .logo-details #btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 22px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  font-size: 23px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.sidebar.open .logo-details #btn {
  text-align: right;
}

.sidebar i {
  color: #fff;
  height: 60px;
  min-width: 50px;
  font-size: 28px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;
}

.sidebar .nav-list {
  margin-top: 20px;
  height: 100%;
}

.sidebar li {
  position: relative;
  margin: 8px 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.sidebar li .tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  left: calc(100% + 15px);
  z-index: 3;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  opacity: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 0s;
}

.sidebar ol,
ul {
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.sidebar li:hover .tooltip {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.sidebar.open li .tooltip {
  display: none;
}

.sidebar input {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: 400;
  outline: none;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  width: 50px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 12px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  background: #1d1b31;
}

.sidebar.open input {
  padding: 0 20px 0 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

.sidebar .bx-search {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 22px;
  background: #1d1b31;
  color: #FFF;
}

.sidebar.open .bx-search:hover {
  background: #1d1b31;
  color: #FFF;
}

.sidebar .bx-search:hover {
  background: #FFF;
  color: #11101d;
}

.sidebar li a {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 12px;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  background: #11101D;
}

.sidebar li a:hover {
  background: #FFF;
}

.sidebar li a .links_name {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  white-space: nowrap;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.sidebar.open li a .links_name {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.sidebar li a:hover .links_name,
.sidebar li a:hover i {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  color: #11101D;
}

.sidebar li i {
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

.sidebar li.profile {
  position: fixed;
  height: 60px;
  width: 78px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -8px;
  padding: 10px 14px;
  background: #1d1b31;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sidebar.open li.profile {
  width: 250px;
}

.sidebar li .profile-details {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.sidebar li img {
  height: 45px;
  width: 45px;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.sidebar li.profile .name,
.sidebar li.profile .job {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #fff;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.sidebar li.profile .job {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.sidebar .profile #log_out {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background: #1d1b31;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.sidebar.open .profile #log_out {
  width: 50px;
  background: none;
}

body {
  background: #E4E9F7;
}

.home-section {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  left: 78px;
  width: calc(100% - 78px);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  z-index: 2;
}

.sidebar.open~.home-section {
  left: 250px;
  width: calc(100% - 250px);
}

.home-section .text {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #11101d;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin: 18px
}

@media (max-width: 420px) {
  .sidebar li .tooltip {
    display: none;
  }
}


/* End Aside */
```

```html
<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">

    <div class="container-fluid">

      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon p-0 m-0">
                        <img class="p-0 m-0" src="{% static 'icons/toggle.svg' %}" alt="" width="35" height="35">
                        </span>
                    </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">PAINEL</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">CNGR</a>
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">REDES</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">VOIP</a>

          <div class="dropdown ">
            <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">
                                    PROFILE
                                </button>
            <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
              <a href="#home">Perfil</a>
              <a href="#about">Logout</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </nav>

</header>

<main>
  <sidebar class="sidebar">
    <div class="logo-details">
      <i class='bx bx-phone icon'></i>
      <div class="logo_name">VOIP</div>
      <i class='bx bx-menu' id="btn"></i>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav-list">
      <li>
        <i class='bx bx-search'></i>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search...">
        <span class="tooltip">Search</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class='bx bx-grid-alt'></i>
          <span class="links_name">Dashboard</span>
        </a>
        <span class="tooltip">Dashboard</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class='bx bx-data'></i>
          <span class="links_name">Database</span>
        </a>
        <span class="tooltip">User</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class='bx bx-chat'></i>
          <span class="links_name">Messages</span>
        </a>
        <span class="tooltip">Messages</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class='bx bx-pie-chart-alt-2'></i>
          <span class="links_name">Analytics</span>
        </a>
        <span class="tooltip">Analytics</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class='bx bx-folder'></i>
          <span class="links_name">File Manager</span>
        </a>
        <span class="tooltip">Files</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class='bx bx-cart-alt'></i>
          <span class="links_name">Order</span>
        </a>
        <span class="tooltip">Order</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class='bx bx-heart'></i>
          <span class="links_name">Saved</span>
        </a>
        <span class="tooltip">Saved</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class='bx bx-cog'></i>
          <span class="links_name">Setting</span>
        </a>
        <span class="tooltip">Setting</span>
      </li>
      <li class="profile">
        <div class="profile-details">
          <img src="profile.jpg" alt="profileImg">
          <div class="name_job">
            <div class="name">Prem Shahi</div>
            <div class="job">Web designer</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <i class='bx bx-log-out' id="log_out"></i>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </sidebar>
  <section class="home-section">
    <div class="text">Dashboard</div>

  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: There can be 2 solution to your problem: 1) You can use `z-index` on header and put it above sidebar . 2) Use `sticky` property to have it stick to top when scrolling

Comment: I tried to apply this solution but it breaks my entire design in the width of my sidebar, and the z-index in my header also had no effect I don't know, would you have any example to show?
Thanks for your attention and help :)

Comment: @EdsonAugusto it is because you have defined high `z-index` value for side-bar then you must apply 1 more than that in `header`

Comment: @Rana It worked, but now my header overlaps the button to open my sidebar kk, but it helped a lot, but just asking in this new scenario would you have any CSS attribute that could help me?
Thank you again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give dashboard `overflow-Y: scroll` and reduce its `width` to `100%-open sidebar width`(flexbox will adjust dashboard´s width automatically if you give sidebar element `min-width: max-content;`). This is how you stick your sidebar in place without using `position` or `z-index`. I will give you a little example

> 

```js
const button = document.querySelector('button');
const sidebar = document.querySelector(".sidebar");

button.onclick = () => {
  sidebar.classList.toggle('active');
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}
.header {
  height: 10vh;
  background: red;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}

.content .sidebar {
  width: 5%;
  background: black;
  height: 90vh;
}

.content .sidebar.active {
  width: 20%;
}

.content .dashboard {
  height: 90vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: green;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}


.content .dashboard .hard-coded-overflow {
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="sidebar active">
      <button class="close">close</button>
    </div>
    <div class="dashboard">
      <div class="hard-coded-overflow">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

You can add transition to make it seem like a proper animation and it is way better user experience than overlaping sidebar on top of main content( that should happen when `media width` is adequate for mobile devices).

Comment: Very interesting your approach, when I read your comment I took it and wrote something similar, it was much more elegant and along with the previous comment I made a version for mobile devices.
Thanks, it helped a lot!

Comment: Great, happy to be of help

Answer (score 1):

As told there can be 2 solutions to your problem :

1. You can use `z-index` on header and put it above sidebar

> For that have use `z-index` value of `sidebar` to be `-1` . As using this you must be careful as some content may overlap(overlay) your sidebar so it is better to leave a `margin` on the `left`

2. Use sticky property to have it stick to top when scrolling

> You have to make a lot of changes in your `CSS` to make a look right now , but for a start you can use `display: block` along `position: sticky` to have a start and improve on the go

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500;600;700&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}


/* Header */

header .navbar {
  font-size: 15px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(260deg, #c16ecf 0%, #2376ae 100%);
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

header #navbarNavAltMarkup {
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

header #navbarNavAltMarkup .nav-link {
  color: #fff;
  transition: all ease 0.2s;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

header #navbarNavAltMarkup .nav-link:hover {
  color: #081145;
  transition: all ease 0.2s;
}

header #navbarNavAltMarkup .active {
  color: #081145;
  font-weight: 400;
}

header #navbarNavAltMarkup .dropbtn {
  background-color: transparent;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-left: 50px;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

header #navbarNavAltMarkup .dropbtn:hover,
.dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
}

header #navbarNavAltMarkup .dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

header #navbarNavAltMarkup .dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: transparent;
  min-width: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

header #navbarNavAltMarkup .dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

header #navbarNavAltMarkup .dropdown a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
}

header #navbarNavAltMarkup .show {
  display: block;
}


/* Test */


/* Mobile */

header .navbar-nav {
  align-items: center;
}


/* End Header */


/* Aside */

.sidebar {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 10;
  height: 100%;
  width: 78px;
  /* background-image: linear-gradient(260deg, #2376ae 0%,#c16ecf 100%); */
  background: #11101D;
  padding: 2px 14px;
  z-index: 99;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.sidebar.open {
  width: 250px;
}

.sidebar .logo-details {
  height: 60px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
}

.sidebar .logo-details .icon {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.sidebar .logo-details .logo_name {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 600;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.sidebar.open .logo-details .icon,
.sidebar.open .logo-details .logo_name {
  opacity: 1;
}

.sidebar .logo-details #btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 22px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  font-size: 23px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.sidebar.open .logo-details #btn {
  text-align: right;
}

.sidebar i {
  color: #fff;
  height: 60px;
  min-width: 50px;
  font-size: 28px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;
}

.sidebar .nav-list {
  margin-top: 20px;
  height: 100%;
}

.sidebar li {
  position: relative;
  margin: 8px 0;
  list-style: none;
}

.sidebar li .tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  top: -20px;
  left: calc(100% + 15px);
  z-index: 3;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  opacity: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 0s;
}

.sidebar ol,
ul {
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.sidebar li:hover .tooltip {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.sidebar.open li .tooltip {
  display: none;
}

.sidebar input {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #FFF;
  font-weight: 400;
  outline: none;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  width: 50px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 12px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  background: #1d1b31;
}

.sidebar.open input {
  padding: 0 20px 0 50px;
  width: 100%;
}

.sidebar .bx-search {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 22px;
  background: #1d1b31;
  color: #FFF;
}

.sidebar.open .bx-search:hover {
  background: #1d1b31;
  color: #FFF;
}

.sidebar .bx-search:hover {
  background: #FFF;
  color: #11101d;
}

.sidebar li a {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 12px;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  background: #11101D;
}

.sidebar li a:hover {
  background: #FFF;
}

.sidebar li a .links_name {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  white-space: nowrap;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.sidebar.open li a .links_name {
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}

.sidebar li a:hover .links_name,
.sidebar li a:hover i {
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  color: #11101D;
}

.sidebar li i {
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  font-size: 18px;
  border-radius: 12px;
}

.sidebar li.profile {
  position: fixed;
  height: 60px;
  width: 78px;
  left: 0;
  bottom: -8px;
  padding: 10px 14px;
  background: #1d1b31;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sidebar.open li.profile {
  width: 250px;
}

.sidebar li .profile-details {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}

.sidebar li img {
  height: 45px;
  width: 45px;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.sidebar li.profile .name,
.sidebar li.profile .job {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #fff;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.sidebar li.profile .job {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.sidebar .profile #log_out {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background: #1d1b31;
  width: 100%;
  height: 60px;
  line-height: 60px;
  border-radius: 0px;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.sidebar.open .profile #log_out {
  width: 50px;
  background: none;
}

body {
  background: #E4E9F7;
}

.home-section {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100vh;
  top: 0;
  left: 78px;
  width: calc(100% - 78px);
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  z-index: 2;
}

.sidebar.open~.home-section {
  left: 250px;
  width: calc(100% - 250px);
}

.home-section .text {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #11101d;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin: 18px
}

@media (max-width: 420px) {
  .sidebar li .tooltip {
    display: none;
  }
}


/* End Aside */
```

```html
<header>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">

    <div class="container-fluid">

      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-controls="navbarNavAltMarkup" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon p-0 m-0">
                        <img class="p-0 m-0" src="{% static 'icons/toggle.svg' %}" alt="" width="35" height="35">
                        </span>
                    </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse " id="navbarNavAltMarkup">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
          <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">PAINEL</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">CNGR</a>
          <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">REDES</a>
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">VOIP</a>

          <div class="dropdown ">
            <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">
                                    PROFILE
                                </button>
            <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
              <a href="#home">Perfil</a>
              <a href="#about">Logout</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </nav>

</header>

<main>
  <sidebar class="sidebar">
    <div class="logo-details">
      <i class='bx bx-phone icon'></i>
      <div class="logo_name">VOIP</div>
      <i class='bx bx-menu' id="btn"></i>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav-list">
      <li>
        <i class='bx bx-search'></i>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search...">
        <span class="tooltip">Search</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class='bx bx-grid-alt'></i>
          <span class="links_name">Dashboard</span>
        </a>
        <span class="tooltip">Dashboard</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class='bx bx-data'></i>
          <span class="links_name">Database</span>
        </a>
        <span class="tooltip">User</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class='bx bx-chat'></i>
          <span class="links_name">Messages</span>
        </a>
        <span class="tooltip">Messages</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class='bx bx-pie-chart-alt-2'></i>
          <span class="links_name">Analytics</span>
        </a>
        <span class="tooltip">Analytics</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class='bx bx-folder'></i>
          <span class="links_name">File Manager</span>
        </a>
        <span class="tooltip">Files</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class='bx bx-cart-alt'></i>
          <span class="links_name">Order</span>
        </a>
        <span class="tooltip">Order</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class='bx bx-heart'></i>
          <span class="links_name">Saved</span>
        </a>
        <span class="tooltip">Saved</span>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <i class='bx bx-cog'></i>
          <span class="links_name">Setting</span>
        </a>
        <span class="tooltip">Setting</span>
      </li>
      <li class="profile">
        <div class="profile-details">
          <img src="profile.jpg" alt="profileImg">
          <div class="name_job">
            <div class="name">Prem Shahi</div>
            <div class="job">Web designer</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <i class='bx bx-log-out' id="log_out"></i>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </sidebar>
  <section class="home-section">
    <div class="text">Dashboard</div>

  </section>
</main>
```

> With 1st solution there also comes some problem like your content will be hidden under header until you scroll . Here you can use `margin` and `sticky` for inside content of sidebar or it is better to improve CSS and go 2nd option

Comment: Got it, thank you very much @Rana of heart treatment!

Comment: You have button to open sidebar than it will be easy though . Just have `sticky` property on it so that it always remain in view part. As sidebar is opened using a button so it can be treated a overlay . So can overlay on header too and this way no need to use (`z-index`) but all calls remain to you .

Comment: Happy to help you @EdsonAugusto